# Spring Integration Async Gateway Response Handling

Tags: response, spring-integration, gateway

I need some hint how to solve a problem with Spring Integration.

I have a Gateway interface.

```
public interface OrderGateway {
   Future<Response> process(Request value);
}
```

I send a request message via the gateway. The ValidationService should check if the data is correct. If yes it should forward the message to the OrderService. The OderService will generate a response.
But if the request data is not correct the ValidationService should generate a response object return it to the gateway.  In that case the OrderService should no be invoked. What kind of message endpoint would be the ValidationService? Would it bit a Router? I would like to a avoid handling this by throwing an exception. How to solve such a situation with Spring Integration?

```
   +--------------------------------+
   v                                |                         
Async Gateway --> CH --> ValidationService --> CH --> OrderService +
   ^                                                               |
   |---------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal way to handle this would be to throw an exception and add an `error-channel` on the gateway; handle the error there and return the validation response from there.

If that's not suitable then, yes, a payload type router would work, with the validation result being sent to a "bridge to nowhere" (a bridge with only an input channel) and the framework will route it back to the gateway.

Comment: Throwing an exceptions works find for me. Thanks a lot.

The only small thing let is that the exception is written into the system out log by the "o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler"

How can a remove the system out? Is the right way to configure a custom logging handler?

Comment: No; simply use your own 'error-channel' instead of the default `errorChannel`.